# Add condition to v-bind?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, binding

Can I add an additional condition to `v-bind`? I'm fine with binding with a single image, but would like to check *if another data has the image already*. **Is there a way to add an additional source in the same `v-bind:src` as a fallback??** Something like:

```js
v-bind:src="getImgUrl(job) | selectedJob.img"
```

or

```html
<img v-bind:src="getImgUrl(job)" onerror="this.src='img/doughboy.png'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `v-bind` can do that expression

```html
<img v-bind:src="getImgUrl(job) || 'selectedJob.img'"/>
```

If not, then `computed` property will be the tool;

```html
<img v-bind:src="getImg"/>
```

```js
computed: {
  getImg() {
    return this.getImgUrl(this.job) || 'img/doughboy.png'
  }
}
```

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: @Vzupo What's the result, the expected result?

Comment: It does not do anything

Comment: v-if is my solution

Comment: I don't know what's in your `getImgUrl`